# Net Core: Does X.Paged List allow Multi Column Sorting?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, pagination

Does X.PagedList allowing Multi Column Sorting, say Sorting by ProductName, and then Product Price? What is the directions and syntax for this? Trying to read the directions here,

https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X.PagedList is just for breaking out an IQueryable/IEnumerable into pages.

Since it takes an IQueryable/IEnumerable, you can sort it however you want.

Using LINQ, you can use stacked OrderBy's to do multi-column sorting.